# Api-Version header is not sent correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, postman

Dear friends I have a weird issue I try to connect to an API and when I try to do the API requests in postman or insomnia everything is okay. When I use the same code on my website and even on localhost the leads request doesn't work and tells me that api-version is not defined.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://affiliate-api.tradingcrm.com:4477/token",
        "method": "POST",
        "data": "{ userName: \"alpt\", password: \"Alpt@12345\" }"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        var settings2 = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://affiliate-api.tradingcrm.com:4477/accounts/lead",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + response.Token,
                "Api-Version": "3",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "data": "{firstName:\"test\",lastName:\"test2\",email:\"test@test.test\"}"
        }
        
        $.ajax(settings2).done(function (response2) {
            console.log(response2.accountId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: `"Api-Version"` I don't think this is a valid header

Comment: this is a valid header if you test this exact header in Insomnia or postman you will get the result perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you check your network tab in the developers tool on the request headers? Perhaps jQuery filters out your headers because of your settings (just suggesting).

Comment: Most probably `Api-Version` header should be `X-Api-Version`, but just with the source code there's no way to know for sure

Comment: https://affiliate-api.tradingcrm.com:4477/swagger/#/ this is the swagger of the manual of my API and username and password is in the source code I provided for testing

Answer (score 5):

Its [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) problem, the API server missing header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` so you cannot set custom request header for example `"Api-Version": "3"`, solution use CORS proxy or retrieve the data from your server or ask your provider to add it.

The different with Postman is postman do not ask server API it just simply send the headers, while `Browser` because different Domain it will asking by doing `OPTIONS` request with following headers before `Post` request made.

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: api-version,authorization,content-type
```

Then the Server API need to response with headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: api-version,authorization,content-type
```

CORS Proxy test:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://affiliate-api.tradingcrm.com:4477/token",
    "method": "POST",
    "data": "{ userName: \"alpt\", password: \"Alpt@12345\" }"
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log('requesting using CORS Proxy.....');
    var settings2 = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://affiliate-api.tradingcrm.com:4477/accounts/lead",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + response.Token,
        "Api-Version": "3",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "data": "{firstName:\"test\",lastName:\"test2\",email:\"test@test.test\"}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings2)
    .done(function(response2) {
      console.log(response2.accountId);
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      console.log(textStatus);
      console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
  })

</script>
```

Comment: The API server or the server I'm trying to run? because all the API tester apps and website can run the code properly if it was API provider server problem they couldn't run it as well.

Comment: I mean API server, apps is different with browser which is very restrict.

Comment: Is there any workaround to fix this issue from my side not server side.

Comment: no other fix except what I told above or contact your API provider

Comment: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com always changes IP I ask the API provider to allow the new IP and on next request the IP changes

Comment: that site is not recommended, it slow. maybe you can create your own cors proxy server. amazon aws has free 1 year or google appengine free forever.

Comment: The API provider confirmed that cors is supported so the problem is that api-version for some reason doesn't get sent properly.

Comment: it supported to make cors request `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but not allowed to set custom request header because missing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: got it let me check

Comment: I'm getting the Access-Control-Allow-Headers * now but still same issue

Comment: I updated the Question with an screenshot from responses

Comment: @AliMahmoudi — Look in the Console. It should tell you that CORS permission has been denied because the response to the preflight OPTIONS request came with a 405 Method Not Allowed status when it requires a 200 OK status.

Comment: I get that error so what will be the next step to fix?

Comment: as quentin said, tell your provider to set http status code `200` for `OPTIONS` request

Comment: I really don't know how to enable it then, worked with manuals of how to do it on IIS 8

added these lines

                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value=""/>

They done this from the API server side but is not working